# Do the words "patiño" and "cabuz" had been accepted by RAE?

Tags: etimología, hispanoamérica, rae, vulgaridades, diccionarios

I had often listened in different programmes translated to spanish on radio and tv coming from Mexico referring to the words.

- Cabuz
- Patiño

The first one I believe it was intended as an euphemism for butt and the other as a synonym for sidekick. At least it is what [this](https://www.significadode.org/cabuz.htm) dictionary tells.

But, does it exist an official position from RAE for these terms or could it be that are only locally used words which should be discouraged to use in any text? Does it exist an already accepted terms equally in terms of euphemism for those?

The thing is that I do not want to make a mistake and use a word which has not been approved by RAE yet, should these words be used in any official document?

If possible I'd appreciate an answer **which could also indicate the etymology or the origin of these words** and if they are accepted or not. Can someone help me to clear out these doubts?

Comment: You can find [_cabús_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cab%C3%BAs) in the DAMER, with the meaning of "last car of a freight train for use by crew members" (from English _caboose_), used in Mexico. I suppose you can derive the "butt" meaning from that. I can't find the other one, could it be a corrupted form of _patada_ o maybe derived from _pata_?

Comment: Hello, Chris, maybe you should change the title of your question and part of the main body as well because you can see for yourself that those words are not registered in the DRAE, it seems that they are not accepted.

Comment: I don't know if their use is "officially discouraged by the RAE" but in any case you could use them in Mexico but you have to check the other countries. The Simpsons translation for Latam is made in Mexico and Sideshow Bob and Sideshow Mel are called Bob Patiño and Mel Patiño but in Colombia most people believe that Patiño is just their last name.

Comment: [Have A and B been accepted], not do. [Does an official position exist etc] Please review your English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno parece que llegué tardísimo a la fiesta pero dejo la respuesta.

> [cabús](https://www.asale.org/damer/cab%2525C3%2525BAs): Último vagón de un tren de carga para uso de los tripulantes.

> [patiño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pati%C3%B1o): Personaje popular, típico de los espectáculos cómicos y que se presta a ser objeto de burla.

El primer término está registrado en el DAMER, como bien había dicho Charlie. El segundo no lo está, pero hay evidencia suficiente de que la palabra existe, como [ésta](https://www.razon.com.mx/columnas/bufones-patinos-y-payasos/) y [ésta](https://q2a.mx/que-es-un-patio.html).

**Saber más sobre el uso de las palabras**

Esto es muchísimo más importante que la respuesta en sí. Hay un par de barbaridades que dijiste y que no las puedo dejar pasar:

> But, does it exist an official position from RAE for these terms or could it be that are only locally used words which should be discouraged to use in any text?

> The thing is that I do not want to make a mistake and use a word which has not been approved by RAE yet

¡No! Que una palabra no esté aceptada por la RAE no significa que sea incorrecto su uso. Hay un montón de palabras que no están reconocidas por la RAE y que además no necesariamente son informales ni regionales, eh. Desconozco qué tan formales sean los términos, pero el uso de ambas palabras es completamente parte del lenguaje estándar por lo menos en México.

Lo peor de todo es que seguro que si fuese una pregunta sobre el inglés, te habrías tomado el laburo de haber comparado con varias referencias; sin embargo, como se trata del español, apenas ves que una palabra no existe en la RAE ya te das por vencido y simplemente concluís que ‘está mal’ usarla. Para que estés un poquito más informado, te recomiendo [este artículo](https://visionlinguistica.wordpress.com/2020/12/14/cuantas-palabras-tiene-el-idioma-espanol-la-rae-miente/). En el mismo se detallan un montón de ejemplos de palabras formales e informales que al día de la fecha no son parte de la RAE.

**Las palabras son de los hablantes y NO de la RAE**. Voy a hacer que éste sea mi lema y me lo voy a llevar a la tumba.